# Perform a pre-image attack on a md4 string?

Tags: hash

I have been given a string and its corresponding md4 hash. I need to find a similar string that would give the same hash.  Below is an MD4 collision example from md4 wiki page; (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4)

I don't understand on what basis the characters were changed. What is the criteria for doing so ?

> Note : The hex characters (**in bold**) has been altered

k1 = 839c7a4d7a92cb**5**678a5d5**b**9eea5a7573c8a74deb366c3dc20a083b69f5d2a3bb3719dc69891e9f95e809fd7e8b23ba6318ed**d**45e51fe39708bf9427e9c3e8b9

k2 = 839c7a4d7a92cb**d**678a5d5**2**9eea5a7573c8a74deb366c3dc20a083b69f5d2a3bb3719dc69891e9f95e809fd7e8b23ba6318ed**c**45e51fe39708bf9427e9c3e8b9

MD4(k1) = MD4(k2) = 4d7e6a1defa93d2dde05b45d864c429b

Note that two hex-digits of k1 and k2 define one byte of the input string, whose length is 64 bytes .

Comment: Those wikipedia examples seem to be bogus.. Before you scratch your head too hard I would suggest you encrypt those examples yourself to make sure you are looking to a valid data. I tested on online services and could not get the same result shown on wiki.
https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/md4.html

Comment: They are not bugus examples. We need to input them as hexadecimals. Try the link : https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/md2 . Make sure you check the hex input box and uncheck Unicode. You will see they give the same hash value.